# LongListMultiSelector doesn't get width of parent item on WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

There is WP8 app.
I have LongListMultiSelector (without any options) that's inside PanoramItem. But actual width of LongListMultiSelector is more than parent PanoramaItem (on my device: 432 vs 444). 
I tried to set HorizontalAlignemt option to "Stretch" but it didn't help me.
What's problem?

Comment: It's all ok with listbox

Answer (score 0):

That's really the problem of using list controls in WP. Try setting the `Width` explicitly, or in the `DataTemplate`'s panel (say you use Grid as your template root panel)

```
<LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="440">
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Is there problem with LongListSelector only? Because there's not one with listbox. Listbox width has right width always. But we have not one display resolution and your solution will be good for only one.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of ScrollViewer of LongListSelector. And because of ScrollViewer phone calculates wrong width of items inside control. I found only one solution — set another margin option of SV and content area in LongListSelector Style. But it's not ideal because in this case ScrollViewer is outside the width you need.